# gem cannot install rails in cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150301-5904-1jxcdlc.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --help
        --clean
/usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:500:in `with_werror'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
        from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
        from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
        from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:599:in `with_cflags'
        from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
        from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Saumyash/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Saumyash/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

please help me...what to do

Comment: *You have to install development tools first*, I guess that's pretty self-explaining.

Comment: i tried, actually i was taking the help of ruby video tutorial to install cygwin, and in tutorial they had an older version of cygwin which had a c compiler file.. and in mine that one is missing...i installed all GCC files yet this problem arises

Comment: "*Check the mkmf.log file for more details*"